# Large numbers in Dart (compilation to JS)

Tags: dart

I was reading [this](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/02/numbers-in-dart.html) blogpost by @seth ladd about numbers in dart, and was wondering whether there is an established way, to deal with big numbers, if the program has to be compiled to java script. I think this could be important in cryptography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two community packages that I am aware of, [bignum](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bignum) and [decimal](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal). There is also an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=681) in the tracker.

You may be also be interested in the [fixnum](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fixnum) package which provides a 64 bit integer which can be compiled to JS.

For crypto in the browser there are also built in browser APIs starting to become available. Here's the lastest [WebCrypto spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).

There is also a [crypto](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/crypto) package, this is implemented in Dart and can be used in the browser and the server. You can see the [source here](https://github.com/dart-lang/crypto).